# MongoDB Cursor Snapshot with C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, cursor

I have a large collection that I need to iterate through. I am using a cursor for this.

However, I noticed I am getting duplicate records sometimes from this cursor. I did some reading and found that I can address this by using a snapshot.

> Cursor Isolation
>   As a cursor returns documents, other operations may interleave with the query. For the MMAPv1 storage engine, intervening write operations on a document may result in a cursor that returns a document more than once if that document has changed. To handle this situation, see the information on Cursor Snapshot.

However, I am unable to find this method in the C# Driver (Version 2.7). I don't see it on `FindFluent` or in `FindOptions`.

Can someone point me to an example of how I can create a cursor snapshot via the C# MongoDB Driver?

Here is what my code looks like.

```
    private async Task<int> IterateViaCursor<P>(FilterDefinition<User> filter, ProjectionDefinition<User, P> pdef, Func<IEnumerable<P>, Task> callback, int batchSize)
        where P : class
    {
        var o = new FindOptions { BatchSize = batchSize };
        var count = 0;
        var findFluent = Users.Find(filter, o).Project(pdef);
        using (var cursor = await findFluent.ToCursorAsync())
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var batchCount = cursor.Current.Count();
                count += batchCount;
                if (batchCount > 0)
                    await callback(cursor.Current.ToList());
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Snapshot was deprecated and then removed for MongoDB 4.0. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32173. So you *'read some old posts"* which talked about snapshot, but this was really just a "band aid" and not a real solution, hence the removal. Instead, explain to us "why" you think you need to iterate a long cursor and the actual code you are using showing you these "duplicates". Even if you are using an older MongoDB server, the solution to your code should not be one using the snapshot option.

Comment: The reason I want to use a snapshot is because I am getting duplicate records when iterating my cursor. I updated my question with some more information

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually reproduces the behavior then? The code provided seems fine, so any issue is likely more related to something else that is happening or other configuration. Note that if you follow though the links from the issue raised to deprecate and remove, it should become apparent that "snapshots" never actually did what most people were expecting them to do, and are also tied to the now removed MMAPv1 storage engine. Newer storage engines have different read isolation by default.

Comment: Was about to talk about something else, but is this the actual code in use? If so then all you are really doing here is "counting" results. Unless there is some other purpose for the code not included here, then there is a far more effective way to to that, instead of iterating a cursor and incrementing a counter.

Comment: Specifically [`MongoCollection.Count(IMongoQuery)`](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Count_2.htm), which I just had to check because some language API's now call this `countDocuments()` or similar, but it's not changed here. This is the recommended reliable way to count query results.

Comment: I am not just counting the results. I call a callback function with each batch.